# Reinstall gitlab on my server

Tags: gitlab, centos7

I've uninstalled gitlab from centos7 server using,using the following commands

```
sudo gitlab-ctl uninstall
sudo gitlab-ctl cleanse
sudo gitlab-ctl remove-accounts
```

Now I'm trying to install it again  following the installation instructions from [omnibus gitlab installation](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#centos-7), but now nothing is installed I try to start with `gitlab-ctl` start but nothing is done, and the files like `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` doesn't exists.

Comment: Please provide error logs or other relevant output during installation.

Comment: All messages are xxxx is already installed  or there is no message

Comment: So, it seems that the omnibus installer is not installing gitlab because it thinks that you already have it installed on your system. Make sure to remove any remnants of the old gitlab install and then retry.

Comment: I'm going to try

Comment: Ok, if solved please close the question.

Comment: I 've deleted `/opt/gitlab`  but is still not working

Comment: I've checked the running tasks with `ps -ef | grep gitlab` and there is agitlab task running

Comment: It would probably be easier for you to do this with a fresh centOS install.

Comment: I know but its not possible

Comment: Did you removed `rpm`? if not remove it as well `sudo rpm -e gitlab`

Comment: @RajanaDeepak, Yes I did

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package using **dnf** or **yum**. **sudo dnf install gitlab-ee**